# How does loop vs forEach work with decrement operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods, foreach

Below JavaScript loop for increment and decrementing which is working for `for-loop`, also it works fine with increment using `forEach` method but how to decrement the same using the `forEach` method?

```js
        let array = [1,2,3,4];
        // increment
        for(let i=0; i <array.length; i++){
          console.log(array[i]);
        }
        // output
        // 1
        // 2
        // 3
        // 4
        array.forEach((elem) => {console.log(elem)});
        // output
        // 1
        // 2
        // 3
        // 4
        // decrement
        for(let i=10; i > array.length; i--){
            console.log(i);
        }

        // output 
        // 10
        // 9
        // 8
        // 7
        // 6
        // 5
```

How do I work with `foreach` when I need to decrement the iteration?
I am looking for usage and limits of `forEach` method. Is it possible or not?

Comment: `forEach` isnt designed for reverse iteration, you can always use trinational `for` for reverse or any order iteration.
if you still need it you can always create a new variable or overwrite elem with `array[array.length-i-1]` (index is passed in `forEach`as second parameter)

Comment: who said forEach is not for reverse operations ??

Comment: What's the point in this for decrement that goes from 10 to 5?

Comment: @JagadishLenka **The docs:** _forEach() calls a provided callbackFn function once for each element in an array in ascending index order._ [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates in increasing order of index, so its not possible to iterate in reverse, while recommended way would be to go with `for` loop, however for any reason you need to iterate in reverse order with forEach, you can do so with calculating relative index and accessing the value.

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].forEach((_, i, ar) => {
  const elem = ar[ar.length - i - 1];
  console.log(elem);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tedious to right out literal array manually, use `Array.from()` it has a secondary `.map()` callback.

```js
const countDown = from => Array.from({length: from}, (obj, idx) => from - idx);

console.log(countDown(20));
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4];
  array.reverse().forEach((elem) => {console.log(elem)});
  array.reverse()
  
  console.log(array)
```

Comment: caution: `.reverse()` actually modifies actual array order.